# Tidy - Handling of Style elements

Tags: php, html, tidy

Is there an option that prevents tidy from moving `<style>` elements out of the `<body>` and into the `<head>`? I know it's valid HTML to have the `<style>` tags in the `<head>`, but there's a particular case where I need to leave them as is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding the scoped attribute to it - I think it is only valid for style tags to be in the body if they have that attribute on it (although only ff supports it and it is classed as obsolete) - https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-style-element.html

Comment: Actually looking at the atest spec for html5, it's only valid to put the style tags in the head: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element

Comment: I had just learned about the scoped attribute earlier today, but then also read a more recent article that support for it was getting dropped.